# Function added with Restangulars extendModel is undefined?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have a service like this:

```
.factory('Car', function(Restangular) {

    var baseCars = Restangular.all('cars');

    Restangular.extendModel('cars', function(obj) {
        obj.extraMethod = function() { console.log('method added'); };
        return obj;
    });

    return {
        show: function(id) {
            return baseCars.one(id).get();
        }
    };
});
```

and a controller like this:

```
.controller('CarCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, Car) {

    Car.show($stateParams.id).then(function(car) {
        $scope.car = car;
        $scope.car.extraMethod();
    });
});
```

However, this results in an `undefined is not a function` error at `$scope.car.newMethod()`.

Does anyone know why this is and how to get it to work?

Comment: I am not very familiar with Restangular, but the method one shouldn't have two arguments one('cars', id)?

Comment: maybe try `show: function(id) {return Restangular.one('cars', id).get()}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you are too close but you missing that when you write

```
Restangular.extendModel('cars', function(obj) {
    obj.extraMethod = function() { console.log('method added'); };
    return obj;
});
```

this only extend object with **'cars'** route...

but your return object's route is whatever your id parameter...

try this code...

```
 factory('Car', function(Restangular) {

    Restangular.extendModel('cars', function(obj) {
        obj.extraMethod = function() { console.log('method added'); };
        return obj;
    });

    return {
        show: function(id) {
            return Restangular.one('cars', id).get();
        }
    };
  }
```

this time return object's route is **cars** and it will have `extramethod()`...